# Filtering custom value from rendering column issue in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1, grid, renderer

I created my own collection with custom data. This is part from my grid class:

```
 my grid class extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
 ...
 $this->setCollection($collection);
 array_walk($data['data'], function($order) use (&$collection) {
            $collection->addItem(new Varien_Object([
                'store_id' => $order['store_reference'],
                'shipping_date' => $order['shipping_date'],
                'order_reference' => $order['order_reference'],
                'customer_reference' => $order['customer_reference'],
                'updated_at' => $order['updated_at'],
                'shipping_fullname' => "{$order['shipping_firstname']} {$order['shipping_middlename']} {$order['shipping_lastname']}",
            ]));
        });
        $collection->setCurPage($page);
        $collection->setLastPageNumber($lastPage);
        $collection->setSize($lastPage * $limit);

        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return $this;
```

where `$collection` is an instance of class which extends `Varien_Data_Collection`. The content of that class is:

```
    protected $hardSetSize = 1;
    protected $setLastPageNumber = 1;
    /**
     * @param int $size
     */
    public function setSize(int $size)
    {
        $this->hardSetSize = $size;
    }
    /**
     * Retrieve collection all items count
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getSize()
    {
        return $this->hardSetSize;
    }

    public function setLastPageNumber(int $lastPage)
    {
        $this->setLastPageNumber = $lastPage;
    }

    public function getLastPageNumber()
    {
        return $this->setLastPageNumber;
    }
```

My grid is displayed, I got my custom data. But there is filtering problem.
I created my column like:

```
    $this->addColumn('store_id', [
        'header'    => Mage::helper('ffm_fulfillment')->__('Store'),
        'align'     => 'left',
        'index'     => 'store_id',
        'renderer'  => 'Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_Test_Grid_Renderer_Store',
        'filter_condition_callback' => [$this, '_storeFilter'],
    ]);
```

I got the render data, which are store ids from 1-20. I want to filter them. I created my `_storeFilter` function. What should I do next ? I put a message and the `exit()` in my function and on filtering I do not get my message.

```
protected function _storeFilter($collection, $column)
{
    $value = $column->getFilter()->getValue();
    echo 'Test'; exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your mentioned code and found you have wrong defined  'filter_condition_callback' => [$this, '_storeFilter'],

```
From
'filter_condition_callback' => [$this, '_storeFilter'],
To
'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_storeFilter'),
```

For more information you can follow the below post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29732847/how-to-create-filter-condition-callback-on-custom-renderer-in-magento-admin-grid

Comment: Nope, is not that I tried both ways, still did not get my message :) . Thank you